# QGIS: Combine the two expressions into one string

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I have two expressions contained in one layer relating to the other layer:

```
array_to_string(overlay_nearest(layer:='gpz', expression:=name))
```

and

```
distance($geometry,geometry(overlay_nearest('gpz',$currentfeature,limit:=1)[0]))/1000
```

I would like to combine these expressions into one string.

Comment: What shoud be the result? To concat the results as string use `||` or `concat()`

Comment: Omg, concat works! Thank u a lot, i dont know how i missed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
concat(
  array_to_string(overlay_nearest(layer:='gpz', expression:=name)),
  distance($geometry,geometry(overlay_nearest('gpz',$currentfeature,limit:=1)[0]))/1000)
)
```